# Should jruby-complete.jar come with rubygems?

Tags: jruby

I am experimenting with jruby-complete.jar and am getting some inconsistent behavior accross different operating systems.

On OS X 10.7 & 10.6 I tried downloading the jruby-complete-1.6.7.jar and running:

```
java -jar jruby-complete-1.6.7.jar -S gem list -l
```

I get an error:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- rubygems
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1033
   (root) at /usr/bin/gem:8
```

So I tried the same thing on a Windows 7 machine:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rake (0.8.7)
sources (0.0.1)
```

Both the OS X machine and the Windows machine are running java version "1.6.0_29". I do not have any ruby installations on the Windows 7 machine, but the OS X machines both have ruby installed.

What would be causing this to not work on OS X but it works on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `RUBYOPT` shell variable to `rubygems` on your OSX box:

```
export RUBYOPT=rubygems
```

...and try again

Comment: I still get the same error after setting the env variable. So, I take it you did not get the same error? It must be an environmental issue on my machine then.

Comment: I do not get the error.  DO you have JRUBy_HOME set (I do not)?  What if you try this: `java -jar jruby-complete-1.6.7.jar -e "puts 'yo'"` ?

Comment: Most of the other commands work fine, like the you you mention here. I do not have JRUBY_HOME set either.

Comment: I copied the jruby-complete.jar from the Windows 7 machine to my OS X machine and that jar file actually works. Maybe I just had a corrupt download. I could check the md5 of the download.